How do I stop Crystal report change my application path?
Everything was working fine when I was using CR13SP24 but had to upgrade to CR13SP35 due to some issues.
After upgrading, my clients facing issues which changes the application directory to C:\Windows\System32\spool\Drivers\x64\3\
This occurs in conditions when

Print to printer
Email Report
Whatsapp Report (using service like twilio.)

The main issue is I am not able to re-create this issue in my pc but many of my clients started facing this issue.
I also created the question about the change of app path in here My question Link.
At that time I was unaware about crystal report changing it.
All I found that whenever I try to run the report in another thread for any of the above mentioned conditions, the app path changes. Irony is that even if I try MsgBox(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), it shows me the actual path which is mostly in D or E Drive but never in C Drive but when I try to create other files like text, excel, etc. , it shows me error that cannot find file on the address C:\Windows\System32\spool\Drivers\x64\3\ even if the createfile command written below the MsgBox command.
Please ask if anything needed.
Thank you in advance.

What if you use Application.StartupPath in combo with Path.Combine() to build your paths? -- If you have concurrent Threads / Tasks, pass the already elaborated path to the routine

I tried many things like Application.StartupPath, System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location or many other things, check the link in the question. Problem is even when I use it in msgbox(Application.startuppath) it gives me correct but a create file command after that msgbox to open or create a file is an error. @Jimi

[...] whenever I try to run the report in another thread [...] -> If you have concurrent Threads / Tasks, pass the already elaborated path to the routine -- Not just the reporting engine you're using now can alter a path, any external assemblies that generate their own AppDomain(s) / ApplicationContext
